# Дубликаты аккаунтов заплодили ruSO :(

Tags: обсуждение

"А почему собственно дубликаты?". И я вам отвечу - акк дубликаты которые плодятся с невероятной скоростью бесят. Вывел из себя один товарищ и его "братья" в особенности:

1. [И раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/514769/semenovnikolu)
2. [И два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/515715/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)
3. [И три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373855/semenov-nilolay)
4. [И четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/268630/nikolay-semenov)

Схожесть между 1,2,4 и 2 - в вопросах которые они задают. Приведу пример - [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442916/view-onclicklistener-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5) и [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1443037/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-room). Они используют один и тот же код, идентичный. Пофиг что ответ принят/не принят, не про это речь.

Оставлял кучу тревог, все они оказались "полезными", их всех апрувнули и на этом все. Я конечно не знаю протокола действий на ruSO для работы с близнецами, но это произвол. Мне кажется с этим нужно что-то делать. Человека забанили на одном акк, он слепил второй, забанили второй - слепил третий. Так мне кажется нехорошо и некрасиво.

Comment: А почему китайцы? Хм.. Это только в начальной версии что ли было? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzopG.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, да в начальной) думал чтобы аналогия была, но потом как-то не прижилось)

Comment: китайцув много и этих аккаунтов куча, и они все одинаковые(

Comment: До тех пор пока человек не автоматизирует создание акков, все норм. Рано или поздно ему надоест смотреть на минусы и блокировку. Если сможет автоматизировать, то скорей всего он не будет задавать вопросы, а цель будет просто навредить. Пока есть активные участники волноваться ее приходиться

Comment: Невероятной скорости не наблюдается. Что-то я не вижу дублирования .. ссылки точно правильные привели? А произвол в чем? А 2 аккаунта из приведенных забанили? В общем, кажется, что такими нечеткими и эмоциональными формулировками вопрос дискредитириует сам себя.

Comment: помню их...я на них в чате свое время тоже жаловался: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61747079#61747079

Comment: относительно дублирования см `builde.gradle` в [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437487/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-failed-to-apply-plugin-com-frogermcs-androiddevmetrics-configuration-w) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437483/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-could-not-find-method-provided-for-arguments)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, ну видать это старожил уже :)